# How to Auto complete double quotation marks in notepad++

Tags: autocomplete, notepad++

Im am using TextFX plugin in Notepad++ and all xhtml and html autocomplete values are opened. Html tags are completing with no problem but i want to insert double "" (quotation marks ) in one button press but only one " mark is occuring. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notepad V6.5.5:

In the "Settings" Menu > "Preferences" > "Automatic conclusion".

Then you can choose what is duplicated when you type.
Example: { [ "" ] }
etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin called `XBrackets Lite`

http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XBrackets%20Lite/